# Pandas dataframes unsort when concatenating

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I extract the same 3 columns (*Names, Pre-score*, and *Post-score*) from multiple different Excel workbooks, turn them into dataframes and `df.sort_values` by *Names* on each.

Calling `print` on them individually shows that they are being sorted alphabetically as required, however when I put them all together in a new Workbook with `all_dataframes = pd.concat([results1, results 2, results3, results4], axis=1)` all the names are unsorted, in whatever order they were filtered by from each individual workbook initially.

Why would this be?

edit: code in full (per each workbook group)

```
names = wb.loc[:, 'Student Name:']
names_df = pd.DataFrame(names)
names_df.columns = ['Group1']

results = wb.loc[:, 'Pre Unit Assessment' : 'Post Unit Assessment']
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

combined = pd.concat([names_df, results_df], axis=1)
results1 = combined.sort_values(by=['Group1'])
```

Comment: please provide a code where you perform sorting, and one more thing You could perform sorting after concat operation also

Comment: I'm guessing you do `print(df.sort_values())`. Hint: What does `df.sort_values()` return? Why does it return something?